# Background timer in swift

Tags: ios, timer, background-process

I am trying to make a system in which my app will add a gem every 30 minutes. I would also want it to run in background so that when the user terminated the app, the gem will still spawn every 30 minutes.

I don't know where to start and what to use. So please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing in the background on iOS is problematic - There are specific background modes for services like location and Bluetooth but no general purpose background execution.

Probably the simplest approach is to store a timestamp in `NSUserDefaults` when the last gem was spawned.  Then, when the app is relaunched you can compare the current time with this timestamp and calculate how many additional gems should be awarded.